# Display last seen status of a web page using java script

Tags: javascript, linux

I have a web page where the data gets updated upon refresh.

I want the user to when the page has been refreshed lastly.

ie if i refresh the page after 3 sec, it should display 3 sec and so on....

Example:

> var current  = "08/06/2014 15:00:00"; // Current time
>
> var next = "08/06/2014 15:00:30";  //Time after Refresh

It should output

> Last seen:30 sec  // (15:00:30 - 15:00:00)

Is there any way to get time after refresh using javascript??

Comment: Is it possible to do it without using any buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `HTML5 LocalStorage` or `Cookies` for storing last seen date, example(uses LocalStorage, save last page open date and show this on next loads):

```
window.onload = function() {
    var lastSeen = localStorage.getItem("lastSeen");
    if (lastSeen) {
        alert("User last seen in " + lastSeen);
    } else {
        alert("User first time logged in page")
    }
    localStorage.setItem("lastSeen", new Date());
};
```

See this example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4KM96/1/)